# Solution to second order linear PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the second-order linear PDE
$$
y_t(x,t) = y_{xx}(x,t) - a^2y(x,t)
$$
where $a > 0$ in all cases and the equation is restricted to the domain $x = [0, X]$. If we have some way of expressing $y(x,t)$ as e.g.
$$
y(x,t) = f(x)g(t)
$$
where both $f(x)$ and $g(t)$ are known, and given boundary conditions \begin{align}
y(0, t) &= y_0(t) \\
y_t(0,t) &= y'_0(t) \\
y_x(X, t) &= 0
\end{align}

**is there an analytical or approximate solution to the PDE?**

Comment: This is a PDE not an ODE and the answer is yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

Comment: Do you mean $\partial y / \partial y$ and $\partial^2 y / \partial x^2$?

Comment: Thank you @Jakob, I fixed my notation.

Comment: Based on your edit, it appears you are stuck at solving ODEs, have you solved second order ODEs before? Particularly ones with constant coefficients? Try the solution $f(x) = e^{rt}$ and find the $r$ which satisfies the resulting characteristic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with the reference @Gregory has provided you. Also, by substituting $y(t,x) = e^{-a^2t}z(t,x)$ you can transform your equation into $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial x^2}$$
a cannonical [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) which has a ready solution.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, could you elaborate? I updated my question to include my attempt to use separation of variables but am curious about your solution.

Comment: Have you tried the substitution I mentioned in the answer? See if you get the same PDE I wrote in my answer. Then check the heat equation link. By the way, the function in your boundary condition is confusing, as there is only one variable in the functions and it is not clear which variable the $'$ is differentiating.

Comment: You need one more boundary condition, e.g. at x=0, to guarantee the uniqueness of the solution unless you do not need the uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, I have worked through it and I think knowing $y_t(0,t)$ as a third boundary condition is sufficient?

Comment: What do you think of the relationship between your first and second boundary condition is? How many boundary conditions do you think you actually have now?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but I do see a problem. $y(0,t) = y_0(t)$ and $y_t(0,t) = y'_0(t)$ are both known real-valued functions at my inside boundary. Therefore I know $y_0(0) = y_{00}$ and $y'_0(0) = y'_{00}$, and I can use these terms to solve for the three constants of integration introduced in the final equation. However, this results in an equation that only depends on the initial values of $y_0(t)$ and $y'_0(t)$, which intuitively does not seem correct.

Comment: That's right. They are redundant. I am saying you should add another independent boundary condition to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: is a constant boundary at $y_x(0,t)$ the only condition that will lead to a solution? It is not appropriate in my system to set $y_x(0,t)$ to a constant; the inside boundary $y(0,t)$ varies with $t$ and I would expect $y_x(0,t)$ to depend on $y(0, t)$ and $y(\Delta x, t)$, but $y(\Delta x, t)$ is something that I am trying to predict. Am I stuck with a numerical approach then?

Comment: You just need another independent boundary condition to make up for 3 independent boundary conditions. Just add another one, say, $y(x,t=0)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is directly solvable with separation of variables as commented by @Gregory---the substitution in the accepted answer is not actually required and leads to the same solution as below.

## General solution

Given the PDE

$$
y_t(x,t) = y_{xx}(x,t) - a y(x,t)
$$
use separation of variables to express $y(x,t)$ as
\begin{equation}
y(x,t) = f(x)g(t)
\end{equation}
Substituting this into the first equation yields
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  & \partial_t \left( f(x)g(t)\right) = \partial_{xx} \left( f(x) g(t) \right) - a f(x)g(t) \\
  \\
  \rightarrow~~~& f(x)g_t(t) = f_{xx}(x)g(t) - af(x)g(t) \\
  \\
  \rightarrow~~~& \frac{g_t(t)}{g(t)} + a  = \frac{f_{xx}(x)}{f(x)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Setting each side of the equation equal to some positive constant $\lambda$ yields two ODEs
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  g_t(t) &= \left(\lambda - a \right) g(t) \\
  \\
  f_{xx}(x) &= \lambda f(x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The solutions to the above ODEs are
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  g(t) &= Be^{\left(\lambda - a \right)t} \\
  \\
  f(x) &= A_1e^{x\sqrt{\lambda}} + A_2e^{-x\sqrt{\lambda}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $A_1$, $A_2$ and $B$ are constants of integration. Combining the two 
solutions yields
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  y(x,t) &= \left( A_1e^{x\sqrt{\lambda}} + A_2e^{-x\sqrt{\lambda}} \right)Be^{\left(\lambda - a \right)t} \\
  &= \left( C_1e^{x\sqrt{\lambda}} + C_2e^{-x\sqrt{\lambda}} \right)e^{\left(\lambda - a \right)t}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants.

## Unique solution

A unique solution will require expressions for $C_1$, $C_2$ and $\lambda$. The boundary condition $y_x(x = X, t) = 0$ at the outside boundary results in
$$
0 = \left( C_1e^{X\sqrt{\lambda}} - C_2e^{-X\sqrt{\lambda}} \right)e^{\left(\lambda - a \right)t}\sqrt{\lambda}
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
C_2 = C_1e^{2X\sqrt{\lambda}}
$$

$C_1$ and $\lambda$ can be solved for given known values of $y(0,0)$ and $y_t(0,0)$; however, this results in expressions
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C_1 &= \frac{y_{00}}{1 + e^{2X\sqrt{\lambda}}} \\
\\
\lambda &= \frac{y'_{00}}{y_{00}} + a
\end{split}
\end{equation}
yielding
$$
y(x,t) = \frac{y_{00}}{1 + e^{2X\sqrt{\frac{y'_{00}}{y_{00}} + a}}} \left( e^{x\sqrt{\frac{y'_{00}}{y_{00}} + a}} + e^{\left(2X - x \right)\sqrt{\frac{y'_{00}}{y_{00}} + a}} \right)e^{\left(\frac{y'_{00}}{y_{00}} \right)t}
$$
This solution does not intuitively seem correct to me because it does not depend on $y(0,t)$ when $t > 0$ (only depends on the initial value). $y(0,t)$ is continuous but not constant, and I would expect it to factor into the solution for all $t$.